# Building flutter tool... Because flutter_tools depends on sockjs_client 0.3.5 which doesn't match any versions, versio

Tags: dart, flutter

My flutter isn't working any more.

Doesn't matter if I type:

```
flutter channel dev
flutter doctor
flutter update-packages --force-upgrade
```

All this commands shows this errror:

```
Building flutter tool...
Because flutter_tools depends on sockjs_client 0.3.5 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to revise your `pubspec.yaml` file to check for the package `sockjs_client 0.3.5` which doesn't match any package at [official dart packages](https://pub.darlang.org) which is the sole repository to get Dart packages for flutter. Check the name and version again, and if it doesn't match one you have to remove it from `pubspec.yaml` if you want the build process to be successful.